# Ejercicio de Hilos ( no sé como completarlo )

Tags: java, hilos

Estoy con un ejercicio de Hilos.
Se trata de un parking.
- Entrada:
- Entran coches si hay espacio. Sino lo hay entonces se quedan esperando.
- Salida:
- Los cotxes se van por un tiempo aleatorio.

El programa el resumen es:
El cotxe que se va tardara un tiempo en volver a entrar. Lo que significa que los coches entraran y saldrán durante 5 segundos.  Una vez pasado esos 5 segunos el parking cerrara sus puertas el controlador avisara las veces que sea necesario para asegurarse que no hay coches ni en la entrada ni en la salida.

Por ahora tengo este programa:

```
public class Parking {

DisposituDeControl dc = new DisposituDeControl();

private void crearCotxes() throws Exception {
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= numCotxes) {
        Cotxe[] cotxe = new Cotxe[numCotxes];
        for (int x = 0; x < numCotxes; x++) {
            cotxe[i] = new Cotxe(50, dc);
            cotxe[i].setName("Cotxe:" + (i + 1));
            cotxe[i].start();
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < numCotxes; x++) {
            cotxe[i].join();
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Parking parking = new Parking(50, 250);
    parking.crearCotxes();

    //Inicializa la simulación del parking 
    try {
        // temporitzador de la simulació
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Fil principal trencat.");
    }

    //Cerramos el parquing.
}
private int numPlaces = 50;
private int numCotxes = 100;

public Parking(int numPlaces, int numCotxes) {
    this.numPlaces = numPlaces;
    this.numCotxes = numCotxes;

}
```

La clase Dispositivo de control:

Tiene que implementar:
 /*
     * void entrada() que gestione el control de la entrada al parking
     * void sortida() que gestione el control de la salida del parking
     * boolea esObert() que indique si el parquing ésta abierto  està intentando cerrar.
     * void avisTancament() que permita avisar a los cotches de que se cierra el pàrquing
     */

```
class DisposituDeControl {
    int[] places;
    int numeroDePlaces;
    int llocsOcupats;
    boolean obert;

    DisposituDeControl() {
        places = new int[numeroDePlaces];
        llocsOcupats = 0;
        obert = true;
    }

     */
    synchronized void entrada(){
        if(llocsOcupats==numeroDePlaces){
              try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    obert = false;
    llocsOcupats++;
    notify();
        }

    synchronized void sortida(){
        if(llocsOcupats>0){
            llocsOcupats--;
            notify();
        }
    }

    synchronized boolean esObert(){
        return obert;
    }

    void avisTancament(){
        obert = false;
    }

    /**
     * Posem a la vostra disposició el metode imprimir per tal que puguei 
     * controlar visualment com es van ocupant i alliberant les places de pàrquing
     */
    public void imprimir() {

        System.out.print("Parking: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("[" + places[i] + "] ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Clase cotxe que simula si un coche intenta aparcar o dar vueltas:

```
class Cotxe extends Thread {
    private static final int MAX_DELAY = 2222;
    private static int nCotxes = 50;
    private DisposituDeControl dc;
    private int ident;

    public Cotxe(int numCotxes, DisposituDeControl dc) throws Exception{
       super(); 
       nCotxes++;
       if(nCotxes <= numCotxes){
           ident = nCotxes;
       }else
           throw new Exception("Error : Massa cotxes creats");  
       this.dc =dc;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try{
                donaVoltesPerLaciutat();
                synchronized(this){
                if(dc.esObert()){
                    dc.entrada();
                    restaAparcat();
                    dc.sortida();
                }
            }
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                System.out.println("Error: cotxe trencat");
            }
        }
    }

    private void donaVoltesPerLaciutat() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(MAX_DELAY));
    }

    private void restaAparcat() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(MAX_DELAY));
    }
}
```

estoy super encallada fijo que hay mil cosas mal.. necesito ayuda urgente!! :(

Comment: Montse tienes suficiente reputacion como para saber, que no vamos a depurar tu programa completo. con que tenes problemas? se mas especifica.

Comment: Básicamente no me muestra nada por pantalla, no busco que nadie me depure nada, pero quizás hay algun error que no veo que alguien si que ve. o alguna cosa que sobre en mi programa..

Comment: Numero de plazas es 0, no me crea ningún coche.. no sé por donde empezar la verdad..

Comment: definitivamente necesitas tratar de identificar los errores y consultar por cosas mas especificas. Una mirada rapida me dice que en el `run()` de un thread no deberias hacer `synchronized(this)` sino `synchronized(dc)` porque quieres el *lock* del objeto de control, no del mismo thread.

Comment: otra cosa que esta mal es que en el metodo `crearCotxes()` comienzas las ejecucion de los threads y ademas esperas que finalicen todos ellos `cotxe[i].join()`, por lo que el `Thread.sleep(5000)` del main se ejecutara cuando los threads finalicen

Comment: ahora me sale este error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Error : Massa cotxes creats
Parking: 
Parking: 
 at ioc.dam.m9.uf2.eac1.b3.Cotxe.<init>(Cotxe.java:22)
 at ioc.dam.m9.uf2.eac1.b3.Parking.crearCotxes(Parking.java:16)
 at ioc.dam.m9.uf2.eac1.b3.Parking.main(Parking.java:30)